# Need Count value from document library and display as look up in list

Tags: document-library

I have a document library Doclib and a list Doclist.

Doclib has columns: Title, Approval Status, Projname(Lookup).
Doclist has Columns: ProjectName, Count(Want to lookup)

The ProjName column is a look up column which fetches ProjectName from Doclist.

I want the column Count to look up how many times a particular project is selected.

Example:

**DocLib**

Title     Approval Status   ProjName

Document1          Draft     Project 1
Document2             Draft      Project 2
Document3             Draft      Project 1
Document4             Draft      Project 3
Document5             Draft      Project 1
Document6             Draft      Project 2

**DocList**

ProjectName   Count
Project 1     3   
Project 2     2   
Project 3     1

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with two lookup columns:

1. Create a lookup column in DocLib that points to itself, column 'ProjName'. Call this column 'ProjNameLookup'.
2. Create a lookup column in DocList that points to DocLib, column 'ProjNameLookup (Count Related)'

See [here](http://pawansatope.blogspot.de/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html) for a guide.

Comment: Thank you for you post! When i try to select ProjName as a lookup for ProjNameLookup. It is not listed in the dropdown.

Comment: Which lookup column are you referring to, 1 or 2?

Comment: I am refering to column no 1

Comment: What is the type of the ProjName column in your DocLib library?

Comment: it is a Lookup column to ProjectName in Doclist

Comment: If ProjName is already a lookup column then you don't need ProjNameLookup, so you can skip column 1 above. In 2 above, the lookup column will point to ProjName (Count Related). Study the link I provided in my answer to fully understand.